# Symmetric header layers with scrlayer-scrpage

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

I've been trying to add some color swatches to the header. So far I've tried Tikz with the usual header commands of `scrlayer-scrpage`, but it didn't work out well. I almost did it, but two problems remain:

1. There is effectively no "background", the layer hides the header content;
2. The headers aren't symmetrical (odd and even pages)

[image]

The page number, as can be seen in the code (relevant part adapted from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224292/coloured-swatch-per-chapter/224302)), needs to be inside the darker rectangle, outside of the text block.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[papersize={216mm,280mm},
inner=22mm,
outer=26mm,
footskip=11mm,
top=24mm, 
bottom=23mm,
headsep=7mm,
footnotesep=4mm,
columnsep=6mm,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum,blindtext}

\usepackage[%headsepline=true,
footsepline=true,plainfootsepline]
{scrlayer-scrpage}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearpairofpagestyles %use after defining page style
\rohead{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\lehead{\llap{\pagemark\hspace{4mm}}AUTOR}


\lefoot*{Some very very long name}
\rofoot*{Some very very long name}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sff\footnotesize}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\sffamily}


\DeclareNewLayer[
background,
oddpage,
align=tr,
hoffset=\paperwidth,
voffset=0pt,%distance from top
%width=1cm,% width of the swatch
width=\paperwidth,
height=\dimexpr\voffset+1in+\topmargin+\headheight\relax,% height of the swatch
contents={\textcolor{lightgray!50}{\rule{9mm}{\layerheight}}
    \textcolor{lightgray!70!black}{\rule{15mm}{\layerheight}} \textcolor{lightgray!50}{\rule{190mm}{\layerheight}}
}% end contents
]{swatch.odd}

\DeclareNewLayer[
clone=swatch.odd,
evenpage,
align=l,
%align=tl,
hoffset=0pt
]{swatch.even}

% add layers to every pagestyle
\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{swatch.odd,swatch.even}



\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Any other possible or simpler solutions, e.g. with TiKz, would be most welcome, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `\AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle` to add the layers before the default layers of `scrheadings`.

But I am note sure what the desired result is. Maybe something like

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[papersize={216mm,280mm},
inner=22mm,
outer=26mm,
footskip=11mm,
top=24mm, 
bottom=23mm,
headsep=7mm,
footnotesep=4mm,
columnsep=6mm,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[footsepline=true,plainfootsepline]
  {scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles
\rohead{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\lehead{AUTOR}

\ofoot*{Some very very long name}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily\footnotesize}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\sffamily\bfseries}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  topmargin,
  addheight=\headheight,
  mode=picture,
  contents=\putLL{\textcolor{lightgray!50}{\rule{\layerwidth}{\layerheight}}}
]{swatch.bg}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=swatch.bg,
  oddpage,
  outermargin,
  addhoffset=2mm,
  width=18mm,
  height=\dimexpr1in+\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight\relax,
  contents={
    \putLL{%
    \textcolor{white}{\rule{1.5mm}{\layerheight}}%
    \textcolor{lightgray!70!black}{\rule{15mm}{\layerheight}}%
    \textcolor{white}{\rule{1.5mm}{\layerheight}}%
    }
    \putC{\makebox(0,0){\pagemark}}
}
]{swatch.odd}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=swatch.odd,
  evenpage,
  addhoffset=\dimexpr1in+\hoffset+\evensidemargin-4mm-18mm\relax
]{swatch.even}
% add the layers to pagestyle scrheadings:
\AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle{scrheadings}{swatch.odd,swatch.even,swatch.bg}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

---

Note: If the layers should be added to every page style (and not only `scrheadings`) as mentioned in a comment of your code then you can use

```
\AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle{@everystyle@}{swatch.odd,swatch.even,swatch.bg}
```

or

```
\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{swatch.bg,swatch.odd,swatch.even}% order changed!
```

---

**Update**

If the pagenumber should be on the baseline of the header, I would use

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[papersize={216mm,280mm},
inner=22mm,
outer=26mm,
footskip=11mm,
top=24mm, 
bottom=23mm,
headsep=7mm,
footnotesep=4mm,
columnsep=6mm,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[footsepline=true,plainfootsepline]
  {scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles
\rohead{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace*{2mm}\makebox[18mm]{\centering\pagemark}}}
\lehead{\makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[18mm]{\centering\pagemark}\hspace*{2mm}}AUTOR}

\ofoot*{Some very very long name}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily\footnotesize}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\sffamily\bfseries}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  topmargin,
  addheight=\headheight,
  mode=picture,
  contents=\putLL{\textcolor{lightgray!50}{\rule{\layerwidth}{\layerheight}}}
]{swatch.bg}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=swatch.bg,
  oddpage,
  outermargin,
  addhoffset=2mm,
  width=18mm,
  height=\dimexpr1in+\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight\relax,
  contents={\usekomafont{pageheadfoot}\usekomafont{pagehead}
    \putLL{%
    \textcolor{white}{\rule{1.5mm}{\layerheight}}%
    \textcolor{lightgray!70!black}{\rule{15mm}{\layerheight}}%
    \textcolor{white}{\rule{1.5mm}{\layerheight}}%
    }
}
]{swatch.odd}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=swatch.odd,
  evenpage,
  addhoffset=\dimexpr1in+\hoffset+\evensidemargin-4mm-18mm\relax
]{swatch.even}
% add the layers to pagestyle scrheadings:
\AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle{scrheadings}{swatch.odd,swatch.even,swatch.bg}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's great. If fact, it's better and cleaner than I expected. If I wanted to change `\pagemark` to be on the baseline of the header, what should I do? I tried changing `\putC` and `\makebox`, but to no avail.

Comment: To ensure that the page number is on the baseline of the header I would add `\pagemark` to `\rohead` and `\lehead`. See my updated answer.